# Master page for PDF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf, file-upload

I am uploading a PDF file using the following code

```
  if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf")
      {
               string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + filename);
                        // Renaming the file uploaded with the ApplicationId 
                        string filePathName = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + filename;
                        string newfilePathName = (Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + Session["ApplicationId"] + ".pdf");
                        System.IO.File.Move(filePathName, newfilePathName);
                        lblStatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                        roUpdate = engeStamp.UpdateAppStatus(5, Convert.ToInt16(Session["ApplicationId"]));

                        Response.Redirect("Estamp.aspx", false);

                        roUpdate = engeStamp.UpdateAppStatus(5, Convert.ToInt16(Session["ApplicationId"]));

       }
```

I need to add a header to the uploaded PDF in all the PDF pages (Like a master page in asp.net)

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of PDF editor API's that are available. My favorite of them is [ActivePDF Toolkit](http://www.activepdf.com/). There are others of varying utilities and price and there is probably some freeware out there as well. ActivePDF will allow you to "stitch" together multiple elements, for instance your header with a users uploaded document.

Comment: Note that while Active PDF itself works well, their licencing leaves a lot to be desired - to the point where we abandoned the product due to the hassles of dealing with it.

Comment: @Chris, what did you replace it with? do you like it?

Comment: Any other ways using 3rd party tools?

Comment: @Jaison, I have looked at the possibility of editing a .pdf document using the .Net tools available and have determined (for myself) that it is just not worth it. This is definitely a case (IMHO) where you want to use a tool that others have built for you. While I agree with @Chris that licensing/pricing for ActivePDF is high, it is 'the best tool'. Maybe somebody else here can endorse a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Cos Callis stated [there are many PDF editor API's available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application). I would like to recommend [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html). You can experiment with the trial version and you will have technical support during your evaluation period. I am part of the development team of this product.